# Processing - Add mousePressed to an animation with 100 balls

Tags: java, processing

I want to create an ArrayList of ball objects, which should be in a loop until there are 100 pieces.

Now my problem: I must implement a function hitTest, so that when you click on a ball it gets removed. In the same position, there should appear two balls then, which go into a different direction. I included mousePressed and a private boolean but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Can someone help me? I am so lost...

Here's my code so far:
Tab 1

```
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

void setup()
{
  size(800,800);
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
  {
    drawBall();
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  //b.update();
  for(int i= 0; i<balls.size(); i++)
  {
    balls.get(i).update();
  }
}

void drawBall()
{
  Ball b = new Ball();
  balls.add(b);
}

void mousePressed()
{
  for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
  Ball ball = balls.get (i);
  if (ball.hitTest())
  {
    balls.get(i).hitTest();
    balls.remove(ball);
    Ball b1 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    Ball b2 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    balls.add(b1);
    balls.add(b2);
  }
}

/*Tab 2:*/

class Ball
{
  private float x;
  private float y;
  private float ballSize;
  private float dirX;
  private float dirY;
  private boolean moving = true;

  Ball()
  {
    this.x = width/2;
    this.y = height/2;
    this.ballSize = random(10.0,30.0);
    this.dirX = random(-3.0,3.0);
    this.dirY = random(-3.0,3.0);
    if(this.dirX<1.0 && this.dirX>1.0)//1 statt -1 macht zufälliger
    {
      this.dirX = 1.0;
    }
    if(this.dirY<1.0 && this.dirY>1.0)
    {
      this.dirY = 1.0;
    }
  }

  public void update()
  {
    stroke(255);
    fill(random(255),random(255),random(255), random(255));
    ellipse( this.x, this.y, this.ballSize, this.ballSize);

    if(this.moving == true)
    {
      this.x += this.dirX;
      this.y += this.dirY;
    }

    if(this.x+ this.ballSize/2> width ||this.x- this.ballSize/2<0)
    {
      this.dirX= dirX*-1;
    }
    if(this.y+ this.ballSize/2> height ||this.y- this.ballSize/2<0)
    {
      this.dirY= dirY*-1;
    }
  }
  
  private boolean hitTest()
  {
    float d = dist(this.x, this.y, mouseX, mouseY);
    if (d < ballSize)
    {
      println("h");
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are very very close! Most of the code you posted is pretty much there.

There are a few syntax issues:

The instructions within the for loop in `mousePressed()` need to be enclosed:

This section here:

```
for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
  Ball ball = balls.get (i);
  if (ball.hitTest())
  {
    balls.get(i).hitTest();
    balls.remove(ball);
    Ball b1 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    Ball b2 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    balls.add(b1);
    balls.add(b2);
  }
```

should be:

```
for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
  Ball ball = balls.get (i);
  if (ball.hitTest())
  {
    balls.get(i).hitTest();
    balls.remove(ball);
    Ball b1 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    Ball b2 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    balls.add(b1);
    balls.add(b2);
  }
}
```

This part on it's own is valid syntax:

```
for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
      Ball ball = balls.get (i);
```

You can use a `for` loop without curly braces, but only if you plan to use a single instruction within the loop. In this case it's retrieving the Ball, which isn't very useful on it's own. Assuming you want to check the condition for each ball, that is a list of multiple instructions which need to be enclosed between `{}`.

(It's a shame Processing only displays this unhelpful error in particular case:

> Consider adding "="

)

One other minor detail is the duplicate call to `hitTest()`:

`ball` is the same as `balls.get (i)` in the context above, therefore calling `balls.get(i).hitTest();` after calling `ball.hitTest()` is redundant. (also nothing is done with the boolean result it returns):

```
for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
  Ball ball = balls.get (i);
  if (ball.hitTest())
  {
    balls.remove(ball);
    Ball b1 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    Ball b2 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
    balls.add(b1);
    balls.add(b2);
  }
}
```

Moving forward you would run into this error:

> The constructor "Ball(int, int)" does not exist

The `new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);` constructor is called in `mousePressed()`, however your Ball class only supplies the default one with no arguments (e.g. `Ball()`, not `Ball(x,y)`.)

You can easily copy/paste your existing constructor and modify it to add the x, y parameters:

```
Ball(float x, float y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.ballSize = random(10.0,30.0);
    this.dirX = random(-3.0,3.0);
    this.dirY = random(-3.0,3.0);
    if(this.dirX<1.0 && this.dirX>1.0)//1 statt -1 macht zufälliger
    {
      this.dirX = 1.0;
    }
    if(this.dirY<1.0 && this.dirY>1.0)
    {
      this.dirY = 1.0;
    }
  }
```

Another option, avoiding duplicated code (which is not recommended) is to call the first constructor:

```
Ball(float x, float y){
    this();// this() calls Ball()
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
```

Full code listing:

```
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

void setup()
{
  size(800,800);
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
  {
    drawBall();
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  //b.update();
  for(int i= 0; i<balls.size(); i++)
  {
    balls.get(i).update();
  }
}

void drawBall()
{
  Ball b = new Ball();
  balls.add(b);
}

void mousePressed()
{
  for(int i = balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
    Ball ball = balls.get (i);
    if (ball.hitTest())
    {
      balls.remove(ball);
      Ball b1 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
      Ball b2 = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY);
      balls.add(b1);
      balls.add(b2);
    }
  }
}

/*Tab 2:*/

class Ball
{
  private float x;
  private float y;
  private float ballSize;
  private float dirX;
  private float dirY;
  private boolean moving = true;

  Ball()
  {
    this.x = width/2;
    this.y = height/2;
    this.ballSize = random(10.0,30.0);
    this.dirX = random(-3.0,3.0);
    this.dirY = random(-3.0,3.0);
    if(this.dirX<1.0 && this.dirX>1.0)//1 statt -1 macht zufälliger
    {
      this.dirX = 1.0;
    }
    if(this.dirY<1.0 && this.dirY>1.0)
    {
      this.dirY = 1.0;
    }
  }
  
  Ball(float x, float y){
    this();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public void update()
  {
    stroke(255);
    fill(random(255),random(255),random(255), random(255));
    ellipse( this.x, this.y, this.ballSize, this.ballSize);

    if(this.moving == true)
    {
      this.x += this.dirX;
      this.y += this.dirY;
    }

    if(this.x+ this.ballSize/2> width ||this.x- this.ballSize/2<0)
    {
      this.dirX= dirX*-1;
    }
    if(this.y+ this.ballSize/2> height ||this.y- this.ballSize/2<0)
    {
      this.dirY= dirY*-1;
    }
  }
  
  private boolean hitTest()
  {
    float d = dist(this.x, this.y, mouseX, mouseY);
    if (d < ballSize)
    {
      println("h");
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've noticed `hitTest()` is using this condition:

```
if (d < ballSize)
```

`ballSize` is used here: `ellipse( this.x, this.y, this.ballSize, this.ballSize);`
which means it's the diameter. Normally for a circle hit test you'd check if the distance is smaller than the radius, not the diameter. Perhaps this is not a bug, but a feature :) ? Allowing for twice the size for easier clicks outside the ball area ?

One other minor suggestion: if you don't want the colours to randomly change multiple times a second, you can create a `color` property to store the random colour once in the `Ball` constructor, then simply reference that set colour in `update()`

You've got most of the tasks done. Remember to take it easy, re-read the code after a break and picture how it would run in your head before running it. It might help find issues like these. It may seem counterintuitive to slow down, but doing so and paying attention to detail will actually speed you up on the long run. Good luck

Comment: Feels like we're on the same shift these days! This is a fine code review in addition to a good answer.

Comment: Even our comments are about timed!

Comment: Thank you both so much! You helped me a lot. Now everything what I wanted works fine.

Answer (score 2):

A small change which could make all the difference would be to add a constructor. Constructors can call one another and have different parameters, so each overload can have small differences.

The best way to write these isn't to copy-and-paste your constructor but to write them in a cascade which avoids making twice the same operation.

As an example, here you could use 2 constructors: one which just creates a ball, and one which creates a ball with specific coordinates. Their signatures would be like this:

```
Ball() // this one creates a ball with pre-choosen coordinates
Ball(float x, float y) // this one creates a ball at these coordinates
```

In a cascade, always try to keep your signature the same and add stuff, by which I mean do it like this (this is a completely fictive class):

```
// a correct way to cascade constructors
MyClass()
MyClass(int a, int b)
MyClass(int a, int b, boolean c)
MyClass(int a, int b, boolean c, String d)
```

Now, there is a prefered order in which you can place your parameters, but I won't go into this as most of the time devs adds them when they need them. The important thing is to avoid doing this:

```
// a bad way to cascade constructors
MyClass()
MyClass(int a, int b)
MyClass(String d)
MyClass(int a, boolean c, int b)
// etc
```

I'm saying this because you want the constructors in your cascade to call one another in an orderly manner which won't multiply manipulations. You don't want a constructor to set some coordinates only for another one to set different values to these same variables!

Of course, there can be a good reason to create a constructor like the one that just takes a String as parameter, but when you will have a situation which calls for this kind of modification, you'll have to think it through so your constructors keep some kind of internal logic. You don't want to spaghetti your constructors, that would be worse than having only one constructor which would be very complicated.

To continue with the example, here is how these constructors could call one another:

```
// a correct way to cascade constructors
MyClass() {
  this(0, 0); // a constructor can call another one by using the keyword 'this'
}

MyClass(int a, int b) {
  this(a, b, true); // keep it simple: the constructors inside the cascade typically just pass the parameters to more complex constructors
}

MyClass(int a, int b, boolean c) {
  this(a, b, c, "defaultName"); // every ignored value is set to their "default value"
}

MyClass(int a, int b, boolean c, String d) {
  // at last, the "real" constructor, which will do most of the work
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.d = d;
}
```

Notice that, in the last example, if you call the `MyClass()` constructor, every parameter of the "real" constructor - the most complex one - will be a default value.

So... to come back to your specific situation, we have a cascade with only 2 different signatures:

```
Ball()
Ball(float x, float y)
```

So, to reproduce the logic I just laid out, you could modify your code like this:

```
Ball() {
  // this constructor will produce balls just like you're used to
  // I just moved the x/y assignation here
  this(width/2, height/2);
}

Ball(float x, float y) {
  // this is your "most complex constructor", you can use it to spawn a ball with custom coordinates
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.ballSize = random(10.0, 30.0);
  this.dirX = random(-3.0, 3.0);
  this.dirY = random(-3.0, 3.0);
  if (this.dirX<1.0 && this.dirX>1.0)//1 statt -1 macht zufälliger
  {
    this.dirX = 1.0;
  }
  if (this.dirY<1.0 && this.dirY>1.0)
  {
    this.dirY = 1.0;
  }
}
```

Please be careful and considerate when you add a constructor. Always reflect on what you're doing, as many constructors serves no purpose but to clutter the program - for now you probably won't notice this side effect, but keep it in mind for when you'll work on bigger projects, especially with teammates or at work. Projects which development and support lasts for years (like real programs) have a tendency to gather a lot of clutter, especially when devs make "small changes" all the time without regard for the structure of the program.

Have fun!

Comment: I was slow on this one :))) Very sound advice (+1). (Your detailed explanations on constructors, using `this(width/2, height/2);`, etc. is better than my answer)